# PHP 2D array for loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I want to create 2d array by using loop. Array should look like this:

```
[00,01,02]
[10,11,12]
[20,21,22]
```

Then I have to search in this array main diagonal.

I know that I need two for loops but I have no idea how to write it. I tried something like this. I know code does not work. I have no idea how to deal with it.

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= $size; $i++){   
    $matrix = [];
    for ($j = 0; $j <= $size; $j++){
        $matrix[i][j] = array ($i;$j);
    }
}
```

For my second task I think I should use foreach and condition. Something like this?

```
    foreach ($matrix as $key) {
        if ($i==$j) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by Main Diagonal? Can you explain more? What do you expect to get out after the loops?

Comment: Are you asking multiple questions? That will require that your question is closed as Too Broad.  The typos in your syntax is another reason to close this page.

Comment: The initialization of the array variable, `$matrix = [];`, belongs outside of the first loop as well, not into it - you don’t want to _overwrite_ the variable with an empty array all the time. And `array ($i;$j)` is just fantasy syntax that makes no sense. If you simply want to concatenate both counter values after each other here, then do that: `$i . $j`

Comment: @CBroe this question has not improved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you reset your $matrix for every iteration in `$matrix = [];` to an empty array. Also your syntax (`array ($i;$j)`) is incorrect. You need to do the initializiation before you loop through the array. The code below will generate you the desired array.

```
<?php
// Generate array
$lastNumber = 2;
$matrix = [];
for ($i = 0; $i <= $lastNumber; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j <= $lastNumber; $j++) {
        $matrix[$i][$j] = $i.$j;
    }
}
```

You dont need to do an if condition to loop through diagonal. You know the exact size and/or positions.

```
// Loop through diagonal
for ($pos = 0; $pos <= $lastNumber; $pos++) {
    // do something with $matrix[$pos][$pos]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly...Try something like this

```
$array = [];
$j = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
if($i % 10 == 0) {
    $j++;
}    
 $array[$j][] = $i;

 }
print("<pre>".print_r($array,true)."</pre>");
```

Which will create:

```
 Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 3
            [4] => 4
            [5] => 5
            [6] => 6
            [7] => 7
            [8] => 8
            [9] => 9
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 11
            [2] => 12
            [3] => 13
            [4] => 14
            [5] => 15
            [6] => 16
            [7] => 17
            [8] => 18
            [9] => 19
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20
            [1] => 21
            [2] => 22
            [3] => 23
            [4] => 24
            [5] => 25
            [6] => 26
            [7] => 27
            [8] => 28
            [9] => 29
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 30
            [1] => 31
            [2] => 32
            [3] => 33
            [4] => 34
            [5] => 35
            [6] => 36
            [7] => 37
            [8] => 38
            [9] => 39
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 40
            [1] => 41
            [2] => 42
            [3] => 43
            [4] => 44
            [5] => 45
            [6] => 46
            [7] => 47
            [8] => 48
            [9] => 49
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 50
            [1] => 51
            [2] => 52
            [3] => 53
            [4] => 54
            [5] => 55
            [6] => 56
            [7] => 57
            [8] => 58
            [9] => 59
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 60
            [1] => 61
            [2] => 62
            [3] => 63
            [4] => 64
            [5] => 65
            [6] => 66
            [7] => 67
            [8] => 68
            [9] => 69
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 70
            [1] => 71
            [2] => 72
            [3] => 73
            [4] => 74
            [5] => 75
            [6] => 76
            [7] => 77
            [8] => 78
            [9] => 79
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => 80
            [1] => 81
            [2] => 82
            [3] => 83
            [4] => 84
            [5] => 85
            [6] => 86
            [7] => 87
            [8] => 88
            [9] => 89
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => 90
            [1] => 91
            [2] => 92
            [3] => 93
            [4] => 94
            [5] => 95
            [6] => 96
            [7] => 97
            [8] => 98
            [9] => 99
        )

)
```

Than loop over it like:

```
$j = 0;
$finalArray = [];
foreach($array as $arr) {
    $finalArray[] = $arr[$j];
    $j++;
}
print("<pre>".print_r($finalArray,true)."</pre>");
```

And you will et out this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 11
    [2] => 22
    [3] => 33
    [4] => 44
    [5] => 55
    [6] => 66
    [7] => 77
    [8] => 88
    [9] => 99
)
```